# WSO2 - questions on "xslt tool","adapters" and "proxy services"

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can someone plese help me answer the following three question on WSO2:

1. Does WSO2 Studio support **tool based graphical xslt transformation**, right now I have to map it to a xslt file created using text editor?
2. Do **all the invocations on WSO2 ESB have to be exposed as "proxy services**", be it consuming a jms message or reading from a file system?
3. Do we have **out of box adapters in WSO2 ESB** to talk to external systems like SAP, Oracle Apps, Siebel, Peoplesoft etc in a drag and drop fashion without any glue code to be written?

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Does WSO2 Studio support tool based graphical xslt transformation, right now I have to map it to a xslt file created using text editor?

Answer:

There is an ongoing effort to implement a Graphical XSLT Transformation tool for Developer Studio. But as I mentioned it is a work in progress. Thus will be available in a future release.

Alternatively, if you are interested you can use existing Smooks editor to perform XML to XML mapping and Graphical Smooks editor in WSO2 Developer Studio will help you to create your smooks configuration with much less effort.

Q2. Do all the invocations on WSO2 ESB have to be exposed as "proxy services", be it consuming a jms message or reading from a file system?

Answer:

If you want to consume a JMS message from a queue or Reading a file using VFS transport, usually proxy services are configured to perform those tasks. But of course you can use Sequences to perform those tasks but then, you need to use these sequences in your proxy service or in REST API.

Q3. Do we have out of box adapters in WSO2 ESB to talk to external systems like SAP, Oracle Apps, Siebel, Peoplesoft etc in a drag and drop fashion without any glue code to be written?

Answer:

No.

Currently IPaaS connector support is not there out of the box for Developer Studio ESB Graphical editor. But it is in Developer Studio road-map which means it will be available in a future release of Developer Studio.

Hope this helps!

/Harshana

Comment: WRT Q3, we have implemented WSO2 ESB connector support in Dev Studio 3.5 version which is scheduled to be released on 22nd of January 2014. Therefore with that version you can import any existing WSO2 ESB connector implemented by WSO2 or any other party and use them in Dev Studio graphical editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default XSLT editor which comes as a XSLT mapping tool or the smooks (recommended for large message processing)editor. Some of the adapters can be found from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/business-messaging/).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but the answer seems quite misleading .Do not see any XSLT mapping tool in WSO2 studio. and my question was around configuration required for adapters.